# What are pros and cons of OneNote "update"?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

I have the full commercial version of OneNote 2010. It is nagging me to update, but I'm not quite sure what it will update to.

I understand there are free versions of OneNote now that have reduced functionality. How do I ensure I don't lose features with an "update"?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand there are free versions of OneNote now that have reduced
>   functionality. How do I ensure I don't lose features with an "update"?

You are mistaken.

> I have read some complaints that the "free" version does not allow
>   local storage of files.

You are mistaken.

> [image]

OneNote for Windows 10 and OneNote 2016 are both free.

> OneNote 2016 (commonly referred to as the “desktop app”) comes with
>   Microsoft Office and runs on Windows 10, Windows 8, and Windows 7.
>   This version looks similar to the other Office 2016 apps like Word,
>   Excel, and PowerPoint. The OneNote 2016 desktop app is also available
>   as a free download from www.onenote.com

Source: [What's the difference between OneNote and OneNote 2016?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-the-difference-between-OneNote-and-OneNote-2016-a624e692-b78b-4c09-b07f-46181958118f)

Comment: Since you are not specific about which features you are worried about losing I am unable to address those concerns specifically.  As pointed out the current desktop version OneNote 2016 and OneNote for Windows 10 (UWP) are both free.  One could argue that OneNote for Windows 10 has more [features](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-OneNote-for-Windows-10-1477d5de-f4fd-4943-b18a-ff17091161ea?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) then the desktop feature except, and the only feature it does not have, is the ability to store your notebook locally.

Comment: Thanks for the link - the situation is worse than I thought!  Imagine a company offering two different programs with the same name, and different, disjoint feature sets!  Neither program will do everything you want, and both have compromises and missing capabilities compared to the other.  That really seems crazy to me.